# Leksah debugger fails because "GHCi is not running"

Tags: debugging, haskell, ghci, leksah

I have just installed Leksah from the binary installer on OSX 10.9.3. Whenever I try to enable debug mode, I get a line in the console saying

`===========127==================`

and when I attempt to perform debug related activities, I get the same error message: GHCi debugger is not running. Clicking "start GHCi" has no effect, and the error pops up on successive tries.
I have created a workspace with a package, and I have configured the package <s>(so it compiles and runs fine from Leksah)</s>. I'm trying to run the debugger from within the default Main.hs source file.

EDIT: It no longer compiles or runs in any predictable way. Compiling and running simply gives me a line of output as described above (for compiling, it shows a =2= and then =127= after a pause). Sometimes running prints the output of an earlier build (having changed main to something else, it still prints "hello"). No errors are shown.

EDIT2: Trying to install on another computer (where I installed Haskell via the installer), I realized that Leksah is supposed to take some time validating packages and whatnot. It seemed to skip this stage on my main computer, where I installed the haskell platform with homebrew. I have the feeling that Leksah can't find GHC at all, but I can't find any preferences pertaining to GHC and related paths.

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into this error on Kubuntu. I had to install the cabal and some dependencies. 
I used the following commands:

```
apt-get install ghc
apt-get install cabal-install
apt-get install libghc-quickcheck2-dev
cabal update
```

This link helped me to find that out: https://code.google.com/p/leksah/issues/detail?id=239